# PendingIntent.getBroadcast().send() vs Context.sendBroadcast()

Tags: android, android-context, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

I am confused between the two functions.

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(...args...).send();
```

and

```
Context.sendBroadcast(...args);
```

Does both the functions do the same thing?
More importantly, which one to use when?

Already read this statement :

> Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast, like calling Context.sendBroadcast().
>
> Source:
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,int,android.content.Intent,int)

The documentation is always complicated. Anything I might interpret wrong?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send a broadcast `Intent`, just call `Context.sendBroadcast()`.

If you want to schedule an alarm or create a notification, that, when triggered, will send a broadcast `Intent`, use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` and pass the `PendingIntent` as an argument to a call to the `AlarmManager` or put it in a `Notification`.

`PendingIntent` is used when you want something to happen later, and you want another app to initiate the action.

Comment: Is the case same for widget intent implemented as pendingIntent?

Comment: Yes. Because the UI of the "widget" is managed by the HOME screen. So when the user clicks on a widget, the HOME screen gets the click and needs to do something. If it needs start an `Activity` or a `Service`, then it uses the `PendingIntent` that your app provided to do this. This is another example of your app delegating authority to another application by passing it a `PendingIntent` which it can send, basically as a stand-in for your app.